# How do I POST a file submission with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have a very simple webpage that allows users to select a file from their OS and 'Submit' to a server running node.js.

I am now in the process of updating the frontend to use jQuery so that I can keep the user on the same page, and then do something useful with the server's response.

I have added jQuery code [as per this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2960356/355682), but doing so has altered the server's ability to actually find (and use) the passed file.

Is there something specific I need to add in when POSTing files?

Relevant HTML:

```
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
  action="http://localhost:3000/file_upload" method ="post">
        <div>
            <label for="pickedFile">Upload CSV: </label><input type="file" name="pickedfile" id = "pickedfile"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button>Send the file</button>
        </div>
</form>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Relevant app.js snippet is as follows:

```
// site/js/app.js

var app = app || {};

(function($){


})(jQuery);

$(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(jsonData){
      console.log(jsonData);
    }, "json");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Relevant server snippet is as follows:

```
var app = express();

//need to configure this before setting up the routes
//if you want file passing to work correctly
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(app.router);
});
app.post('/file_upload', function(req, res) {
    //file should be in req.files.pickedfile

    // get the temporary location of the file
    // When using jquery, pickedfile is undefined!
    var tmp_path = req.files.pickedfile.path;
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Express part seems to be just fine, however the jQuery code would need a plugin like 
[jQuery.Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), which handles multipart form submission:

```
$("form").ajaxForm({
  data: {
    extraParam: "foobar"
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("Uh oh, something went wrong");
  },
  success: function( response ) {
    alert("Upload completed!");
    console.log( response );
  }
});
```

Comment: I have used [this small plugin](https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js/blob/master/README) and was happy with it. My use case required me to automatically send the multipart form immediately upon file selection.

Comment: So I've now got jQuery.Form working (the file is uploaded), but neither the success nor error callbacks trigger. Do I have to change something about the server's response to get jQuery to acknowledge it?

Comment: Not really. Is the server already returning something on upload? If Express is returning `204 No Content`, the browser may not do anything with the response, or if you're setting the response to JSON but not valid JSON is being returned, jQuery could fail.

Comment: @gustavohenke The server is *supposed* to return a JSON object (`res = jsonResult`) to it in the function I outlined above), but the webpage doesn't get it, eventually timing out with "no data received".