# Showing server response after uploading a file to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an HTML5 input control which is allowing the end user to upload a .csv file:

```
<input id="ImportFile" type="file" name="ImportFile" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a file" title="Browse for a file to upload" />
```

This is housed nicely in a form which allows me to submit the uploaded data to the server:

```
verify: function () {

    //  Run form validate to style controls if they're invalid.
    var isValid = this.form.valid();

    if (isValid) {
        this.isVerifyInput.val(true);
        this.form.submit();
        this.isVerifyInput.val(false);
    }
}
```

During verification, the server needs to be able to inform the user of errors which were encountered while verifying their uploaded file.

As such, my form targets a hidden iframe which consumes the submit's page refresh action:

```
<form action="/csweb/Component/ImportComponents" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ImportComponentsForm" method="post" name="ImportComponentsForm" target="UploadTarget">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsVerify field is required." id="IsVerify" name="IsVerify" type="hidden" value="false" class="valid">
    <input id="ImportFile" type="file" name="ImportFile" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a file" title="Browse for a file to upload" class="valid">
</form>

<iframe id="UploadTarget" name="UploadTarget" class="uploadTarget"></iframe>
```

Where I am then notified of the submit completing:

```
this.$el.find('iframe.uploadTarget').load(this.onUploadComplete.bind(this));
```

**This doesn't work because I don't have any way to read a server 'response' after the form submit, of course.**

However, I am left a bit confused. Articles on StackOverflow regarding this issue suggest serialization of form data:

- [Submit a form and get a JSON response with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960321/submit-a-form-and-get-a-json-response-with-jquery)

As far as I am aware -- it is not possible to serialize the uploaded data and POST it to the server. My understanding is that uploaded data must be sent through form.submit. Is this correct?

If so, how can I provide server side verification of uploaded content? It would appear my only option is to submit the form, temporarily record the information server-side, wait for the load event of the iframe and then issue a GET request to the server to retrieve any potential messages. Is that my only option?

Comment: File uploads are a pain.. Your other option is to use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) object to send the form post asynchronously... but FormData isn't supported by <IE10. I would recommend using a community-proven solution like [jQuery FIle Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), which can fallback to an iframe approach when FormData isn't available.

Comment: I'll take a look at jQuery FileUpload, thanks. I do need to support IE8+.

Answer (score 0):

We can post serialize form data using ajax 
but it will be faild for file upload case.

Check bellow url for file upload using ajax

http://www.scriptiny.com/2013/02/simple-file-upload-using-ajax/
http://zurb.com/playground/ajax-upload